# He has existed since before

Tags: grammar

> He has existed since before the creation of the world.

Does this sentence mean he isn't created?

Comment: If you want an ELL answer on the meaning of the words, this is the right place.  But if you want to know how the follower of the several religions interpret statements like this, you'd do better at [islam.se] or [judaism.se] or [hinduism.se] or [christianity.se]

Answer (score 1):

No, it says nothing about if "He" was created other than, if he was created, it was before the world was created.

Comment: What if I change the sentence to *he's existed since before the creation of all beings, everything, living or non-living*? Does it mean he is not created?

Comment: @Stephen Not necessarily. It all depends on if "he" is considered a being, If we are talking about a god then his status is defined by the particular religion of which he is a part. Some gods are considered eternal, to have existed forever and had no creation event. Some gods are created by various means such as springing forth from natural phenomena or as the children of other gods for example. Where these theories collide with cosmology and the Big Bang is beyond my pay grade.